# mysql query to exclude duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a quick question. I have the following table in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_agp_settings_data` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agp_user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `agp_order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `agp_blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `agp_keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `agp_keywords_date` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `wp_agp_settings_data` (`ID`, `agp_user_id`, `agp_order_id`, `agp_blog_id`, `agp_keywords`, `agp_keywords_date`) VALUES
(1, 2, 5, 4, 'keyword1', '1369872000'),
(2, 2, 0, 6, 'keyword2', '1369872000'),
(3, 2, 0, 3, 'masterkey', '1369872000'),
(4, 2, 0, 4, 'testkey', '1369872000');
```

I would like to get only distinct agp_blog_ids.
So far I did this:

```
SELECT agp_blog_id
FROM wp_agp_settings_data
WHERE
        agp_user_id = 2
        AND (agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%keyword1%" OR agp_keywords NOT LIKE "%key1%")
        AND agp_keywords_date BETWEEN 1369872000 AND 1370044800
GROUP BY agp_blog_id
```

However I would like to exclude result "4" at all because one record already matched the conditions.

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: it should return only 6 and 3 because all "4" match by the date range

Comment: I don't understand why 4 shouldn't be retrieved, dates are all the same. What do you mean with "all 4 match by the date range"?

Comment: Well, I would like if agp_keywords column match any of the keywords that I am looking for and date is within the specified range, it should not return the agp_blog_id that matched the conditions - it should return the rest blog ids. Hope that helps.

Comment: But, 4's agp_keywords is not like 'keyword1' or 'key1'. That's why it's been outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT agp_blog_id
FROM wp_agp_settings_data
WHERE
        agp_user_id = 2
        AND agp_blog_id NOT IN(
                SELECT agp_blog_id FROM wp_agp_settings_data WHERE agp_keywords LIKE "%keyword1%")
        AND agp_keywords_date BETWEEN 1369872000 AND 1370044800
GROUP BY agp_blog_id
```

This will exclude any results that have 'keyword1' in the agp_keywords column.  You can add additional keywords to be excluded inside the 'NOT IN' block

Comment: Thanks David. That's what I was looking for. I knew it was something small to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

You can change NOT LIKE to LIKE and then negate that OR block.

It goes as follows:

```
SELECT agp_blog_id, agp_keywords
FROM wp_agp_settings_data
WHERE
        agp_user_id = 2
         AND !(agp_keywords LIKE "keyword1%" OR agp_keywords LIKE "%testkey%")
         AND agp_keywords_date BETWEEN 1369872000 AND 1370044800
 GROUP BY agp_blog_id;
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9c4e8/22).